# Character motion jump

Tags: game-engine, physics

[image]

So I'm not good at blender and you can see that. My problem is that I added a control like jump and whenever I press spacebar the character does not go back to the floor. If this is related to physics I tried some but I can't seem to find the right one and for a character where should I put the physics armature or the main character?

And also when I use some physics it makes my character fly or go up nonstop

Comment: 1st step is to make your character( the parent one) dynamic.
Also can you toggle the keyboard character so I can see it?

Comment: What do you mean by the parent one, the bone? because when I parent the bone with the mesh the bone is what I selected first. There I added another picture @Lev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen online the method usually followed by the character is the following:

- Add a small cube. Fix its size to be almost from the feet to the knees of the character.Then make the lowest part of the cube to be in the same height with your character's feet.
- Add every motion SCAs to that cube. Only add animations to your character. So the cube will decide where you go and the character when to play the walking/jumping animations.
- Set the cube's physics to "character" or "dynamic" or what suits you. Gravity will automatically affect it then.
- Last don't forget to parent everything to your cube.

Tip: In order to remember which to select first for parenting think this. When a ship goes down, you pick the children first and then the parents. So the last thing you select is a parent. Read that somewhere.

Edit: Forgot about the bones's physics. Set that to no collision if you don't want it to interact with stuff. Also I think that the parent's physics would overwrite the childrens's. So even if bones was dynamic nothing would make them move differently.

Comment: I'll try that method and by the way thanks for answering and one last question if I had the character and decided to do it with the cube thing, how do you make the cube invisible so that it won't appear in the game, just the character.

Comment: In the physics toolbar of "Dynamic" and "Character, below the option "Actor" , there is an "invisible" option. Just select it and you 'll be ok.

Comment: Hi again, sir. Can I ask questions if by chance you are still here or not busy?

Comment: Keep asking and I ll keep answering if I know. But if they are different to this thread, open new ones.

Comment: Can it be like this? And when I start the game the character doesn't follow the animation, or the stand pose I made. ( I changed the picture since I don't know how to add picture comments or it is not possible. )

Comment: Don't mind the sensor not connected to the "and" I connected it but still doesn't work or the character doesn't play or follow the pose/animation I made

Comment: Upload your .blend file here : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/  and I'll have a look at it. Also if you are making a standing pose, deactivate true level triggering in the always sensor and make the action ping pong.

Comment: How do I get the link of the download?

Comment: Or is it this http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37657

Comment: Make the "Sphere.001" a child of the armature and then make the armature a child of the cube and it works.

Comment: And if I want the character to be followed by the camera, which one do I parent

Comment: Make the camera a child to the object that you want to track. In your game I guess it won't rotate so fix it first to see the screen that you like and make it a child to the cube.

Comment: Ok I'll try to fix things and thank you for answering my dumb questions. Ok goodbye.